# Tortoise and Hare race coding In PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sample Output
In [1]: runfile('.../proj01.py', wdir='...')

How many miles will the tortoise and hare race? **1**

How many inches can the tortoise cover in one minute? **30**

The tortoise takes 35.199999999999996 hours to finish the race.

How many miles can the hare run in one hour? **5**

How long does the hare rest (in min)? **60**

How long does the hare run at a time (in min)? **10**

The hare takes 1.2 hours to finish the race.

In [2]: runfile('.../proj01.py', wdir='...')

How many miles will the tortoise and hare race? **3.5**

How many inches can the tortoise cover in one minute? **100**

The tortoise takes 36.96 hours to finish the race.

How many miles can the hare run in one hour? **1.5**

How long does the hare rest (in min)? **5**

How long does the hare run at a time (in min)? **60**

The hare takes 2.5 hours to finish the race.
In [3]:

Note: In both of the sample interactions, the user entered the numeric text (highlighted in green) after each of the questions; the program generated the remaining text (using the input and print functions).

I've posted a sample output for the project.Im trying to work on writing codes but I am having huge confusion and problems.

1. I know how to output and let the users type the numbers but I don't know the third part where you need to get to an answer from the given numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the basic word-problem concept that a rate is expressed as distance per unit time.  This comes in three forms:

```
distance = rate * time
rate = distance / time
time = distance / rate
```

If you know two of the items and need the third, choose the equation that has the two known items on the right side.  Also note that you will have to compute the number of inches in a mile: 12 inches/foot * 5280 feet/mile.

Does this get you going?

Comment: i got the formula part but I don't know how to continue wording after The tortoise takes 35.199999999999996 _______  <- this part I don't know how to continue writing my word after this.

Comment: Then you need to be more clear with your question, please.
I suggest these actions, in order:
(1) Read how to use a Python print statement.  Most basic tutorials and textbooks contain this information.  We expect you to attempt your own research before you post here.
(2) Post an example of the code you have already, and where it's not working for you.  In this case, I expect to see a computation statement and the print after that, with the output or error you did get.
(3) Read the posting guidelines so you know how to do these things for your next question.